# Is there any support of custom AbstractCMSComponentContainer in Spartacus (SmartEdit)?

Tags: spartacus-storefront, smartedit

I had the following data model in backend:

```
AccordionComponentContainer extends CMSTabParagraphContainer
AccordionItemComponent extends SimpleCMSComponent
```

*The container extending the CMSTabParagraphContainer because extending the
AbstractCMSComponentContainer is pain in the ass (generated jalo classes has
to be adapted but this isn't important for this case, only for
understanding.*

Now I have a component in Spartacus CmsAccordionComponent. I introduced a
component mapping:

```
AccordionComponentContainer: { 
  component: CmsAccordionComponent, 
},
```

In my component html file I have something like this:

```
<h2>{{headline$ | async}}</h2> 
<ul> 
  <ng-container *ngFor="let component of components$ | async; let i = index"> 
    <li>{{component.content}}</li>
  </ng-container> 
</ul>
```

I used the files in
`projects/storefrontlib/src/cms-components/content/tab-paragraph-container` as
reference for my implementation (e.g. component implementation). Expect of ng-template (cxOutlet):

```
<ng-template [cxOutlet]="component.flexType" [cxOutletContext]="{}">
  <ng-container [cxComponentWrapper]="component"></ng-container> 
</ng-template>
```

Before, I tried the same solution as CMSTabParagraphContainer. For some reason this won't work in my project. I introduced an own component and a mapping for the children (AccordionItemComponent) but it didn't work. The child components aren't shown.

So I used my solution described above. With my solution the components are displayed (also the child components) but I cannot edit them in SmartEdit. Maybe it's related with this issue: https://github.com/SAP/spartacus/issues/1484.

For testing purpose I added the 'normal' CMSTabParagraphContainer with
CMSParagraphComponent's to my content slot in the backoffice. And I can edit
the first CMSParagraphComponent that is shown in SmartEdit. Unfortunately I
cannot add new paragraphs to the CMSTabParagraphContainer. Therefore I think
that the ng-template (cxOutlet) solution is the better one as mine.

**Can you please explain how the TabParagraphContainerComponent and the snippet
ng-template (cxOutlet) works?  Also I think that this should considered in the
github issue ticket (https://github.com/SAP/spartacus/issues/1484) so that
CMSTabParagraphContainer (AbstractCMSComponentContainer) are better supported
in Spartacus (SmartEdit).**

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The most important piece is the `cxComponentWrapper`. This directive takes the component slot data and renders the component inside.

The `cxComponentWrapper` requires the following data set for each component:

```
{
  flexType: item.typeCode,
  typeCode: item.typeCode,
  uid: item?.uid
}
```

A typical container component template implementation would iterate over the various components and applies the directive:

```html
<ng-container *ngFor="let item of items$ | async">
  <ng-container
    [cxComponentWrapper]="{
      flexType: item.typeCode,
      typeCode: item.typeCode,
      uid: item?.uid
    }"
  >
  </ng-container>
</ng-container>
```

The problem that you'll likely face, is the lack of the component `type` in the container component cms data. The cms api will only expose the component UIDs for the various nested components. You need to fetch the component type from the backend, using `CmsService.getComponentData`. You need to do this for each component uid. If you do this in a loop, Spartacus will actually merge the various calls to CmsService.getComponentData and do a single call to the backend.

An example of such an implementation can be found at https://github.com/SAP/spartacus/blob/746a15c1b63998065b0ceea96f4da052829533fb/projects/storefrontlib/src/cms-components/content/banner-carousel/banner-carousel.component.ts#L25.

Comment: Thank you, I added to my pipe           

   map((test: CmsAccordionItemComponent) => {
                return {
                  ...test,
                  flexType: test.typeCode,
                };
              })

and it works now.

Comment: Should I open a feature request for __Unfortunately I cannot add new paragraphs to the CMSTabParagraphContainer.__. When yes, where should I create the feature request?

Comment: It would be great if you can indeed open that feature request on our repo. We can then evaluate if this is indeed an issue and - if so - if we can fix it.